# How to fix escaping in json response

Tags: c#

Im trying to deserialize a json response i get.

The json response i get is weird (3 \\ escaping) :

```
\"{\\\"isSuccess\\\": false, \\\"value\\\": null, \\\"errorCode\\\": 0, 
\\\"errorMessage\\\": \\\"An exception of type vmodl.fault.NotSupported 
occurred.Arguments: n()\\\"}\""
```

I tried replacing the \\ but it didnt work so well

```
var contentCorrected = response.Replace("\\\\", "");
```

Any help would be appreciated.  i would upload my code if necessary.

Comment: How are you getting this response? Something seems off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's the "real" value (visible in i.e. Fiddler) and not a copy-paste from the Visual Studio variables view? It looks like it was escaped twice.

Try this one:

```
var json = s.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Comment: Its the response from the visual studio view...
if i print the response i get :

    "{\"isSuccess\": false, \"value\": null, \"errorCode\": 0, \"errorMessage\": 
    \"An exception of type vmodl.fault.NotSupported occurred.Arguments: 
    \\n()\"}"

When im getting response from other frameworks i get a different json